# Access ImageMagick's man page

Tags: man, imagemagick, documentation

On my system I have *ImageMagick* and its documentation installed:

```
$ apt-cache pkgnames imagemagick
imagemagick
imagemagick-6.q16
imagemagick-dbg
imagemagick-doc
imagemagick-common
```

I can access `convert`'s *man* page, which tells me SEE ALSO `ImageMagick(1)` if I want to know more.

`man ImageMagick` says `No manual entry for ImageMagick`.

And finally, `man -k imagemagick` says:

```
quantize (5)         - ImageMagick's color reduction algorithm.
```

How do I access [*ImageMagic*'s *man* page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/imagemagick) on my system?

## Additional information

Above I was mistaken.
`apt-cache pkgnames` listed packages are "not necessarily available to download, installable or installed" (ref. `APT-CACHE(8)`).
So, my command did not list the installed packages.

Digging more, I ended up with

```
$ apt list imagemagick*                                                                        
Listing... Done
imagemagick/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.4 amd64 [installed]
imagemagick-6.q16/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
imagemagick-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.4 all [installed,automatic]
imagemagick-dbg/xenial-updates,xenial-security 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.4 amd64
imagemagick-doc/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.4 all
```

So, apparently, `imagemagick-doc` was not installed.
Nevertheless, this package installs the `www` documentation (`/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-doc/www`) and not the *man* one.

Checking the content of the `imagemagick` package does not give away what the name of its *man* page is, or at least, I am not able to figure it out.

```
$ dpkg -L imagemagick | grep man
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/stream-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/display-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/animate-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mogrify-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/composite-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/montage-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/import-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/identify-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/conjure-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/convert-im6.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/compare-im6.1.gz
```

## Bug reports here

- ImageMagick: I've opened a bug report [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=31522).
- Debian: another bug report [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=856997).

Let's see if someting comes up.

Comment: FWIW, Fedora includes `/usr/share/man/man1/ImageMagick.1.gz` (so `man ImageMagick` works as part of the main `ImageMagick` package.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, and there is no such *man* page in my system.

Comment: I was just looking for this the other day, so thanks for asking! It looks like Debian lost it [between 2012-12-24 and 2013-05-10](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/imagemagick.git/log/debian/imagemagick.manpages?id=refs/heads/debian/6.8.9.9-5%2bdeb8u7) though I can't tell exactly when or why (the file referencing it was renamed then renamed back, and I'm not sure how to track the in-between filename through the git web client).

Comment: @drewbenn, it looks like it has been removed [here](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/imagemagick.git/commit/debian/imagemagick.manpages?id=cba6526ceca97ddee3ab205574becfc3873aedfc) and forgotten [here](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/collab-maint/imagemagick.git/commit/debian/imagemagick.manpages?id=cd0f82d5c8d1414f6b2340a7edbba5e49c30ff4e), if I got this right. Shall we open a bug report to *Debian* packages maintainer?

Comment: Yes, it looks like a problem in Debian packaging, not upstream, so [Debian BTS](https://www.debian.org/Bugs/) would be the correct place to report the bug. You could file it against Ubuntu instead, since that's where you're actually seeing it, but in this case that's probably just a roundabout way of informing the same people.

Comment: OK, I've submitted the bug report to Debian BTS. I'll add the link to the main question when I get my tracking number. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick used to have great man pages, but the author decided HTML was the way of the future and now the man pages are mostly just a big mishmash of irrelevant options and instructions to go the web for real documentation. The missing ImageMagick man page you mention was (if I recall correctly) just a list of the commands (convert, composite, display, identify, montage, etc.).

For that reason, I often install [`GraphicsMagick`](http://graphicsmagick.org) which retained the useful man pages when it forked from ImageMagick. (You may also wish to install `graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat`).

Comment: I've managed to have the missing man page recovered by Debian folk.

Comment: Good job. Is it a useful man page? If not, `graphics-magick` may still be useful to you.

Comment: As you said, these man pages need some love. I don't want to rely on the Internet to check the syntax of local commands, when there's a local documentation available.